# Make the web application auto-determine and know its version

Tags: java, web-applications, build, build-process

My team are doing with 2 teams: server team and client team. We at server team will provide APIs for the client team to call. The APIs have many version, so that we need to match the server build and the respective client build - for example, the old client will refuse to work if the server build number is much larger than its support version and requires an update.

Because of the above reason, we need to send back the build version of server to client. Currently we are doing this by adding a static field in a Config class. But I'm concerned with the fact that we must manually increase it everytime a new server is built - especially when we do daily build. This process is quite error-prone and not quite elegant.

In my search, I see many propose for using maven plugins to manage the build version. Though I highly appreciated the auto-process, it still doesn't let the server know the build number. Server application should be able to return its build version to client through an API call.

I have thought of write the number version somewhere (remote database, files on server).
 **Is there any way to make the building process automatically increase the build version, but the application itself can retrieve this number in running also?**

We are using Maven build and having Jenkin as the integration build server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually read the version from the `MANIFEST.MF` file that is packaged in the JAR by Maven.
By default it looks something like this:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Built-By: user
Build-Jdk: 1.6.0_35
Created-By: Apache Maven 3.0.4
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver

Name: Artifact
Implementation-Build: 1.14-SNAPSHOT
Version: 1.14-SNAPSHOT
```

From this file I read the Version element and use that to for instance display the build version of the application (and all versions of the packaged jars in a WAR/EAR for instance).
Something like this code should work:

```
public static String getApplicationVersion() {
        String version = null;
        try {
            final List<VersionsUtil.Version> moduleVersions = VersionsUtil.getModuleVersions(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());
            for (VersionsUtil.Version moduleVersion : moduleVersions) {
                if (moduleVersion.name.equals("<NAME OF ARTIFACT TO GET>")) {
                    version = moduleVersion.version;
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // We'll return null...
        }
        return version;
    }


public class VersionsUtil {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(VersionsUtil.class);

    /**
     * Returns a list of the module versions available for the given class loader.
     *
     * @param classLoader the class loader to return module versions for
     * @return a list of module versions
     * @throws IOException in case there's an error reading the manifest
     */
    public static List<Version> getModuleVersions(final ClassLoader classLoader) throws IOException {
        return processResources(classLoader.getResources("META-INF/MANIFEST.MF"));
    }

    private static List<Version> processResources(final Enumeration<URL> resources) throws IOException {
        final List<Version> moduleVersions = new ArrayList();
        while (resources.hasMoreElements()) {
            URL resource = resources.nextElement();
            Version v = process(resource);
            if (v != null) {
                moduleVersions.add(v);
            }
        }
        return moduleVersions;
    }

    private static Version process(final URL resource) {
        try {
            Properties p = readResource(resource);
            return createVersion(p);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOG.warn("Failed to read resource: " + resource, e);
            return null;
        }
    }

    private static Version createVersion(final Properties p) {
        Object name = p.get("Name");
        if (name != null) {
            return new Version((String) name, (String) p.get("Version"));
        }
        return null;
    }

    private static Properties readResource(final URL resource) throws IOException {
        LOG.trace("Reading resource: " + resource);
        InputStream is = resource.openStream();
        Properties p = new Properties();
        p.load(is);
        is.close();
        return p;
    }

    public static final class Version {
        String name;
        String version;

        private Version(final String name, final String version) {
            this.name = name;
            this.version = version;
        }

    }
}
```

Updated:
If you want Jenkins buildnumber in the `MANIFEST.MF` you can configure your `POM.XML` with something like:

```
  ...
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <configuration>
      <archive>
        <manifestSections>
          <manifestSection>
            <name>${project.name} (${project.artifactId})</name>
            <manifestEntries>
              <Version>${project.version}${build.number}</Version>
            </manifestEntries>
          </manifestSection>
        </manifestSections>
      </archive>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
  ...
  <properties>
     <build.number />
  </properties>
  ...
```

If you're interested in tagging the WAR/EAR files instead, you have to add the manifest configurations accordingly. 
Then in your Jenkins job configuration, simply pass the `BUILD_NUMBER` parameter to the maven process like this: `-Dbuild.number=$BUILD_NUMBER`.

Comment: sorry I don't see your answer earlier, but does that mean I must use Maven to control my version? I'm not familiar with that process. Could you point me to some tutorial (I can't find a relevant source by google)

Comment: "We are using Maven build and having Jenkin as the integration build server." I thought you used maven to build and package?

Comment: yes, we use Maven, but we don't use the Maven versioning. We only use it for packaging and deploying

Comment: Ok . The method described will work anyway - with minor changes. You do have versions of some kind I hope?

Comment: You can get the current build number from jenkis from the BUILD_NUMBER property - this can be used as the version in your pom.xml to indicate the current version. And then written to the Manifest.mf file automatically to be retrieved with the code above :)

Comment: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project#Buildingasoftwareproject-JenkinsSetEnvironmentVariables for reference

Comment: Updated the answer with maven manifest information. Send me a PM if you need more elaborate instructions.

Comment: Thanks Peter, I think that it may work. I will try it and response to you as soon as possible.